# Changepoint Analysis R programming

Tags: r

I am a PhD researcher with little to no programming experience. I want to apply a changepoint analysis to a dataset. I was already able to install and load this package, apply this to a dataset and get a graph, but I also want to see the changepoint printed on my screen. How do I do this? Because when I type print(m.pm) I get a summary with the number of segments etc. but not the actual value...
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrE3o.png)

Kind regards

Comment: Glad you got some help.   Also suggest using RStudio as your R IDE: https://rstudio.com/products/rstudio/  Easy to install and use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, the setting you are using returns the position of change points so you will have to filter in your `data` vector:

```
library(changepoint)
#Data
data <- c(423,436,456,461,516,529,534,601,642,673,832,1291,1814,2950,5123)
#Code
m.pm <- cpt.meanvar(data,penalty = 'SIC',test.stat = 'Exponential') 
data[m.pm@cpts]
```

Output:

```
data[m.pm@cpts]
[1]  832 5123
```